# Drawing a connected set of nodes on an axis

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to draw a set of joined-up nodes on an axis at specific coordinates.  I have attempted:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \draw[->,thick] (0,0)--(8,0) node[right]{$t$};
  \draw[->,thick] (0,-2)--(0,4) node[above]{$y$};
  \foreach[count=\i] \coord in {(0,0),(0.5,0),(1,3.9),(1.5,2),(2,0),(2.5,0),
    (3,0),(3.5,0),(4,0),(4.5,0),(5,0),(5.5,0),
    (6,0),(6.5,0),(7,0),(7.5,0)}
  {
    \node (n\i) at \coord {\tiny\textbullet};
  }

  \foreach \i in {2,...,16}
  {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\result}{\i - 1}
    \draw (n\result.center) -- ({n\i}.center); % problem line
  }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The problem lies in drawing the connecting lines with the nodes; I get the following error:

```
ERROR: Package PGF Math Error: Unknown operator `c' or `ce' (in '0.center').
```

I'm not sure if I'm going about this the right way or how to fix the error.  Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You may try `\pgfmathsetmacro{\result}{int(\i - 1)}`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See, if you replace

```
  \foreach \i in {2,...,16}
  {
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\result}{\i - 1}
    \draw (n\result.center) -- ({n\i}.center); % problem line
  }
```

in your code with

```
  \foreach \i [count=\j from 1] in {2,...,16}
     \draw (n\j.center) -- (n\i.center); % problem line
```

gives what you looking for.

[image]

Comment: Ah, I didn't think about using a second counter for the preceding node; nice idea.  Thanks!